# converting array element to integer in elif body causing error

Tags: python-3.x

```
command_count = int(input())
array = []
for i in range(command_count):
    command = input().split()
    print(command)
    if command[0] == "insert":
        array.insert(int(command[1]),int(command[2])
    elif command[0] == "print":
        print(array)
    elif command[0] == "remove ":
        array.remove(int(command[1]))
    elif command[0] == "append ":
        array.append(int(command[1])
    elif command[0] == "sort":
        array.sort()
    elif command[0] == "pop":
        array.pop()
    elif command[0] == "reverse":
            array.reverse()
    else:
        pass
```

*Error*

```
elif command[0] == "print":
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It says syntax error but when I replaced the elif body containing int(command[]) with pass the code ran without the error.

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: The reason you are getting an error is the previous line should be changed from ```array.insert(int(command[1]),int(command[2])``` to ```array.insert(int(command[1]),int(command[2]))```.  The new line has the closing parethesis.

Comment: Thank you. The command ran without any errors and worked as intended